# Text to speech not working for other languages (except English)

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I was trying to do a text to speech operation in my app. For English, it works properly. But, for other languages, it does not produce any audio. There is no error while debugging in device. I used the method in adapter for a listview.

Here is the code (adapter):

```
tts=new TextToSpeech(getContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.speakEnglish_words.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String textto=holder.txtTitle3.getText().toString();
            tts.speak(textto, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    });
```

Here is the activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_image_scrolling);

    btninfo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.infobtn);
    showimage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_imageview);
    categ_txtview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordtitletxtview);

    showimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.accommodationforall);
    categ_txtview.setText(""+category);

    Test_Adapter_Bargaining_temporary adapter=new Test_Adapter_Bargaining_temporary(Accomudation_words.this,Englishwords,Arabicwords,Arabicsounds);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.test_listview);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    btninfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Accomudation_words.this,InfoDialog_accommodation.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did that answer help?

Comment: Hi,
Actually not.

I did solve the problem myself :) 

but, 
thanks for commenting. :)

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: Hi,
Its so silly problem. Need to turn on the internet connection. the code was fine. :)

Comment: Can be closed as 'unreproducible or typo'.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found a solution.

Just needed to turn on the Internet connection. The code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to see if you have the french text to speech engine for french on your phone using a method described here: [Google Text to Speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499438/google-text-to-speech)

There is also a device setting for the language described here:

https://tunesgo.wondershare.com/android/text-to-speech.html